# Using ifelse statement on the whole dataset instead of a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to use ifelse on a whole data frame instead of a single column.

If my data is like this;

```
Var1     Var2     Var3
 1        1        1
 3        2        0
 0        1        2
 3        3        1
 5        0        3
```

To change individual columns, I would have done

```
Var1_Binary<-ifelse(data$Var1 == 0, 0, 1)
Var2_Binary<-ifelse(data$Var2 == 0, 0, 1)
Var3_Binary<-ifesle(data$Var3 == 0, 0, 1)
```

But I would like to do ifelse to the whole data set - I have a lot of variables and it would be time consuming to do ifelse on each one.

So, the final dataset would look like this

```
Var1     Var2     Var3
 1        1        1
 1        1        0
 0        1        1
 1        1        1
 1        0        1
```

thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
DF[] <- as.integer(DF > 0)
DF
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    1    1
#2    1    1    0
#3    0    1    1
#4    1    1    1
#5    1    0    1
```

---

In case you want to extend your dataframe, try

```
DF[paste0(names(DF), "_Binary")] <- as.integer(DF > 0)
DF
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var1_Binary Var2_Binary Var3_Binary
#1    1    1    1           1           1           1
#2    3    2    0           1           1           0
#3    0    1    2           0           1           1
#4    3    3    1           1           1           1
#5    5    0    3           1           0           1
```

**data**

```
DF <- structure(list(Var1 = c(1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 5L), Var2 = c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 0L), Var3 = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "Var3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(. == 0, 0, 1)))

# or...
data %>%
  mutate_all(funs(as.integer(. > 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `lapply`:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(x != 0)))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    var1 = c(1,3,0,3,5),
    var2 = c(1,2,1,4,0),
    var3 = c(1,0,2,1,3)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution using `ifelse` on each column:

```
data.frame(Map(ifelse, list(df==0), 0, 1))

  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1    1
2    1    1    0
3    0    1    1
4    1    1    1
5    1    0    1
```